# How can I stop elpy from overriding some of my keybindings?

Tags: emacs

I just updated the emacs package elpy, and it's set the following keybindings:

```
<M-down>        elpy-nav-move-iblock-down
<M-left>        elpy-nav-move-iblock-left
<M-right>       elpy-nav-move-iblock-right
<M-up>          elpy-nav-move-iblock-up
```

I usually have these keys bound to `windmove-<direction>` and I think this is a real pain. Following [this github issue](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/288), I tried:

```
(load "python")
(define-key elpy-mode-map [remap windmove-left] nil)
(define-key elpy-mode-map [remap windmove-right] nil)
(define-key elpy-mode-map [remap windmove-down] nil)
(define-key elpy-mode-map [remap windmove-up] nil)
```

in my `.emacs`, but no luck. How can I stop `elpy-mode` from overriding these keys?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can reset the offending mappings to `nil` in one fell swoop in the following way.  *UPDATE.*  As per lunaryorn's comment, the file parameter should be `"elpy"` rather than `"python"`, which is now reflected in the answer.

```
(eval-after-load "elpy"
  '(cl-dolist (key '("M-<up>" "M-<down>" "M-<left>" "M-<right>"))
     (define-key elpy-mode-map (kbd key) nil)))
```

If you're not keen on the `dolist`, you could wrap four calls to `define-key` in a `progn` within the `eval-after-load`.

Comment: `elpy-mode-map` is defined in `elpy`, not in `python`.

Comment: I don't use `elpy`, so I was basing the `"python"` part off of OP's code.  I presume the file name is `elpy.el`, so I'll make a note in the answer itself.